# ng-invalid not working on select tag - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I tried the below code:

HTML

```
<select id="selectReason" name="selectReason" class="form-control" ng-options="reason as reason.reasonName for reason in dataCtrl.data.reasons" ng-model="table.reason" ng-required="table.needReason" ng-show="table.needReason">                              </select>
```

CSS

```
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
border-color: #FA787E;
```

}

OUTPUT Tag

```
<select id="selectReason" name="selectReason" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-options="reason as reason.reasonName for reason in dataCtrl.data.reasons" ng-model="table.reason" ng-required="table.needReason" ng-show="table.needReason" required="required"><option value="" class="" selected="selected">
</option><option label="No Material" value="object:18">No Material</option>
<option label="Machine Breakdown" value="object:19">Machine Breakdown</option>
</select>
```

And later I also added the ng-invalid css.

As soon I click on submit the select tag gets the "ng-invalid" class in its class attribute but the red border is not displayed

Please help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: `ng-dirty` isn't a class on your `select` tag, so the CSS isn't applied

Comment: thanks gtlambert. So how can I make ng-dirty to been added there

Comment: presumably it is easier to just change your css selector to `.ng-invalid`

Comment: this fixed my issue thanks a lot.
But what made ng-dirty to not been added there.
If the field is invalid ng-dirty has to be added by angularjs right ?